# split it using java

Tags: java

i need to split and string

```
    Sentence:NounPhrase| VerbPhrase
    NounPhrase:Art| Noun
    Sample:the
```

this should be written As

```
Sentence:NounPhrase
Sentence :VerbPhrase
NounPhrase:Art
NounPhrase: Noun
Sample:the
```

how can i do this using java

Edited

the file `expression.txt`

```
Sentence:NounPhrase VerbPhrase
NounPhrase:Art Noun
VerbPhrase:Verb|Adverb Verb
Art:the|a
Verb:jumps|sings
Noun:dog|cat
```

the program i used but not working

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
public class shift {
    public static String readFileFull(String file)
    {
         String strLine = null;
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try{

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));



            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                sb.append("\n");      
                sb.append(strLine);      
                }



            in.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            String ret=sb.toString();
            return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String speech = readFileFull("c://expression.txt");


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(speech);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] ps = sc.nextLine().split(":");
            for (String s : (ps[1] + "|").split("\\|"))
                if (!s.equals(""))
                    sb.append(ps[0]+":").append(s).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());




    }

}
```

and try to tell me y i am still getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FileRead {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\expression.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            // Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String a[] = strLine.split(":");
                String b[] = a[1].split("\\|");

                for (String s1 : b) {
                    System.out.println(a[0] + ":" + s1.trim());
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You will run into ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if your input strings do not strict to the format you mentioned...you need to take care of that case.

Comment: @Sundhar..Well...you need to feed your input line by line to the above code snippet to make it work...how do you get the input? are you reading from a file? or is it a single string?

Comment: @Sundhar - you should be using BufferedReader , readLine() to read the contents of your file line by line - I gave the full solution now..check out.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple logic of:

- Split the string by key value (separator is `:`) `K, V` pair.
- From value `V` separate it further with `|` (Resulting in `v`)
- Foreach v in `V`: add `v` in a list.
  Finally:
- Add list of `v`'s in a `Map<K, List>`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 separators `line breaks`, `:` and  `|`. so I think you should read line by line then `split` twice.